# How to fix Oracle trigger causing recursion issue

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I don't know if I'm clear enough with my question. I have a database for a transport company that stores the date and time of all trips, I'm trying to prevent someone from reserving a ticket an hour before the scheduled departure time or buying a ticket after the departure date and time.
I've tried creating a trigger for this but for some reason it does not allow me to create a ticket if it complies with the time requirements. It gives me an error

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00036: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded
ORA-00036: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded
```

Here's the code for my trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER validHour
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON ticket
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE x number;
BEGIN
select EXTRACT(DAY FROM (departure - sysdate)) * 1440 + EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (departure - sysdate)) * 60 + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (departure - sysdate)) 
into x
from trip
where trip.tripid=:new.tripid;

IF :new.status = 'Reserved' AND x<= 59 THEN
    raise_application_error(-20000,'You can only reserve an hour before departure');
ELSIF :new.status = 'Purchased' AND x<= 0 THEN  
    raise_application_error(-20000,'You can only purchase before departure');
ELSE
    INSERT INTO ticket(name, lastname, status, reservationid, cardnumber, tripid, seatnum)
    VALUES(:new.name, :new.lastname, :new.status, :new.reservationid, :new.cardnumber, :new.tripid, :new.seatnum);
END IF;

END;
/
```

If creating a trigger for this isn't the correct way, how else could I do this?

Comment: Should your before insert trigger be calling insert?

Comment: `select (departure - sysdate) * 60 * 24 from trip` will give you an amount of minutes between these dates, no need to `extract`

Comment: @beherenow I didn't know that! I struggled so much getting this value and I wish I knew it was as easy as this. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you insert another row within the trigger. If you don't raise the error, let it go. The insert will go on since the trigger was fired *because* of the insert in the first place. You don't have to insert again the same data.

By inserting another row in `ticket`, you fire the trigger again, etc. which leads to the stack exception.

This:

```
IF :new.status = 'Reserved' AND x<= 59 THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'You can only reserve an hour before departure');
ELSIF :new.status = 'Purchased' AND x<= 0 THEN  
    raise_application_error(-20002, 'You can only purchase before departure');
END IF;
```

is enough. (I corrected the error numbers)

Answer (score 2):

Your trigger is being called recursively because you are performing another insert in it.
Take the insert out. A BEFORE INSERT trigger is called as part of the insert/update DML.  If your validation passes, there is nothing else you need to do, as the insert will complete.

Comment: Thank you! This does the trick. I didn't know there's no need to insert after checking.